# Minecraft immediate death upon re-spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time i log into minecraft now, i'm trapped in the nether above a pit of lava, i have no control of movement and i burn up within seconds. I can no longer play multiplayer because i cannot spawn away. Please help?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to contact the operator of the server.

Comment: oops, sorry @GnomeSlice I didn't see your comment here when I posted my answer!

Comment: @chands if you look at the timestamp, you'll see that your answer was here before my comment.  I didn't notice it when I commented. :P

Comment: oh, aha! failure on my part. I saw 8 minutes for you and 10 minutes for me and somehow in my head and i looked at them like ranks. And you were beating me, but clearly i failed.

Comment: Why would your spawn be in the nether? Beds explode if you try to set your spawn there

Answer (score 13):

Contact the server administrator and ask them to move you to somewhere safer.

Answer (score 2):

If the server allows flight, you could equip yourself with there flight mod and fly to safety.

All you have to do is Google "Zombe Mod Pack" and you'll get instructions on how to do that. Hope this helps!

Comment: [That's not helpful...I have the itch to downvote answers suggesting that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: @Bobby Why? It's a solution to the problem.